# Visual Studio 2017 V.15.2 Hangs When Disable Internet Connection?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

Visual Studio 2017 V.15.2 Hangs When Disable Internet Connection.

I used Re-sharper 2017.1.2

Comment: Are you using TFVC for source control?  It does not work well when you are disconnected from the internet

Comment: Not Used From Source Control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution ?
Visual Studio 2017 15.2 (26430.12) is now available for download. The latest update brings bug fixes and performance improvements. The new version fixed an issue where Visual Studio freezes without a network connection as well as added support for Service Fabric 5.6 release/2.6 SDK which enables using ServicePackageActivationMode=”ExlusiveProcess”.